# Laravel POST method going to GET

Tags: php, laravel, api, http-post

I have a problem that I can not resolve in Laravel 5.4.
I'm using the Postman extension to make requests for my API, so far it works normally with GET, but when I try to do a POST, the method that's actually called is GET again. (The API can not have authentication or token for the user).

**api.php:**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::group(['api' => ['auth:api']], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function(){
        Route::get('{id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@getUser']);
        Route::post('', ['uses' => 'UserController@saveUser']);
        Route::get('', ['uses' => 'UserController@allUsers']);
        Route::put('{id}',['uses' => 'UserController@updateUser']);
        Route::delete('{id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@deleteUser']);
    });
});
```

**UserController.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller{
    protected $user = null;
    public function __construct(User $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function allUsers(){
        return $this->user->allUsers();
    }
    public function getUser($id){
    }
    public function saveUser(){
        return $this->user->saveUser();
    }
    public function updateUser($id){
    }
    public function deleteUser($id){
    }
}
```

**User.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    public $hidden = ['venda','remember_token', 'created_at','updated_at'];
    public $fillable = ['nome','email', 'venda'];
    public function allUsers(){
        return self::all();
    }
    public function saveUser(){
        $input = Input::all();
        echo 'aa';
        $user = new User();
        $user->fill($input);
        $user->save();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change this:

```
Route::group(['api' => ['auth:api']], function(){
```

To:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){
```

Comment: Now the following error occurs: "InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:
Route [login] not defined."
(This API can not request authentication)

Comment: can you paste your js file?

Comment: also, you can revies this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) I guess it's have what you need

Comment: I can add the `<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>` in the js?

Comment: no you add it in the blade file, eg. head.blade.php